# How can I set the `c` variant for the `/RTC` option if I need it?

Tags: c++, visual-studio

MS Visual Studio 2015.

According [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8wtf2dfz.aspx) it is possible to point `c` as value of the `/RTC` key. But I don't see this variant in the items of combobox:

[image]

If I choose the `Default` item then I see the `/RTC1` variant is applied again:

[image]

If I set this value manually:

[image]

then I see the `/RTC` option disappeared from command line:

[image]

Why for the `/RTC` key of the Visual Studio C++ project is absent the variant `c` in the combobox? How can I set this variant if I need it?

Comment: Isn't that the "Smaller Type Check" in the box just above?

Comment: Note that this option will make your code not standard C++ conformant!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For unknown options (for the IDE, not for you), you can add it manually to the  *Additional Options* box in the *Command Line* settings.

But this particular option is not forgotten, it is just next to it, named *Smaller Type Check*. It is not in the combobox that you signal because it is independent of it. That is you can compile with `/RTC1` alone, with `/RTCc` or with both `/RTC1 /RTCc`.

You can argue that `/RTC1` is actually `/RTCs /RTCu` and that those two are also independend. You would be right, and of course, the proper GUI would be one checkbox for each of the options. Probably it is this way for historical reasons.